# How to validate an email address using XSLT 2.0?

Tags: regex, email, xslt, xslt-2.0

How can I use XSLT 2.0 to validate an email-address? Is there a predefined method or do I have to build a regex-expression?

Thanks

Comment: You can't build a regex for Email-validation yourself. But you could use one that is publicly available.

Comment: @Vince: Thanks for your comment. So I guess there is no pre-defined method or a method in an available framework?

Comment: I don't know about xslt, but if there is, I'm pretty sure, you'd find it in the documentation/google somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this in XSLT 2.0 but you will have to use a regular expression (although writing a regular expression that can actually match all possible email addresses is another matter).

In the case of using a regular expression, you would use the **matches** function to check if a string matches the regular expression for an email address (where $email is a variable containing the string to validate. Alternatively you could use element name containing the email address).

```
<xsl:if test="matches(upper-case($email),'^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$')">
   Valid
</xsl:if>
```

Check out http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/06/04/tr.html for information on regular expressions.

Note that I got the regular expression from this example from http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html. In this case, it assumed it was upper-case, hence the use of the function in my example.

Comment: Thank you Tim, that helps a lot.

Comment: Note that to support all possible emails, you'd have to use a slightly more complicated regular expression: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address/1917982#1917982

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use XPath 2.0's [**match()**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-matches) function in XSLT 2.0 to test a candidate email address against a regular expression.

However, whether it is a good idea to use [**regular expressions to validate an email address**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323/290085) is another question.  See the cited SO question and answers for candidate regular expressions as well as warnings about the limitations of using regular expressions to validate emails addresses in general.